# Django website yields error which does not appear when run locally

Tags: django

I have a Django 1.9-driven website run on Ubuntu, and I very often face a strange issue that some error vanishes when I run the clone of the project locally from my PC using `127.0.0.1:8000` url. Locating the error in such cases is EXTREMELY time consuming and I wonder what are the best practices for debugging a large-scale project, especially when the website is already partially in use.
Just to be as specific as possible, I provide a step-by-step description of what goes wrong.

Step 1. I type some url, say, `10.8.0.1:8000/show_students/`

Step 2. Do some action on the page, say, save a student profile. The operation does not end successfully, yielding an error.

Step 3. I copy-paste the project directory located on the remote server onto a local directory on my PC and try to run the CLONE. I see that the error does not take place.

Real-life example,

```
task_email_recipients = TaskEmailRecipients.objects.get(task_type = 
task_instance.type, legal_entity_own = legal_entity_own_instance)
```

This line throws exception saying that `LegalEntityOwn has no field named` (yes, I did not omit anything. It is empty string after "field named")
If I run the same view from 127.0.0.1, the error goes away. 
What should be my actions ? 
BTW, I use Eclipse if this makes any difference. And I have MS Windows 10 on my local PC.

Summing up, my goal is to debug the project run from 10.8.0.1

UPDATE for – Paul Becotte's comment
I've always ignored this warning, but when running the project, it gives a warning

> You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until
>   they are applied. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Comment: Are you... A. Using source control?  B.  Using migrations to control the schema of your database?  C.  Deploying your app in an automated way?  Problems like this usually come from messing around on the deployed server and then forgetting you did so, and getting better control over what is actually running in both locations will usually resolve these problems.

Comment: Paul, see the updated question. Could you please clarify both points (A. and B.) ?

Answer (score 1):

So, let me explain a few concepts.

A.  Source Control (Git) lets you keep track of all the changes to your source code.  This is pretty important so that you can feel confident that you are running the same version of your code on your development machine as your deployed server without trying to do something like copy the files back and forth.  A command like `git status` can show you if you changed something and maybe give you tips on what is different between the two environments.  If you are not using git, you should immediately start!

B.  Migrations are like source control for the schema of your database.  A SQL database like Mysql or Postgres has a fixed schema- you have THIS many tables, with THESE names, and table A has three columns with one of them called Name and one called ID and so forth.  Migrations are designed to give you visibility into what these schema are- instead of logging into the database and running `CREATE TABLE A ...` you build a migration file that contains the necessary commands, and then stamps the database with a version number.  Then you run those command files so that if the databases are on the same version, you know they have the same structure (which allows you to get your local database to match your deployed one).  Django has a helpful migration system all built in... `manage.py migrate` is a command to apply all of the migration files to the current database.  If you are getting the error message you listed, there is basically no chance that your app IS going to work properly, because your database schema, somewhere, is out of sync with your model files.  Based on your very limited description, you added a field to a model that now exists in your local database but does not exist in your production database.

C.  I mentioned a deploy script- this is a single command you can run to get your code running on your remote server so that you are sure it happens the same way every time.  In this case it might be something like...

```
ssh production
git pull
python manage.py migrate
uwsgi
```

Set up a script like that so that you know what is going on, and you can rule out accidentally skipping steps as an error vector.